Getting 404 error when sending notification
I am using Firebase to send app notification in PHP 5.6, CodeIgniter 2.15.
The fcm token just seems to expire of past 2-3 days in many case and getting this error:
[fblurojit] => {
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Requested entity was not found.",
    "status": "NOT_FOUND",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.firebase.fcm.v1.FcmError",
        "errorCode": "UNREGISTERED"
      }
    ]

But if user just logged in today then notification is sending but not in all phones.
And how can I send notification in batches in this v1?
function sendNotificationBulk($message = null, $title = null, $imageUrl = null, $usernamesString = null)
{
    $usernamesString = '"fktmctsantosh","fblurojit","fktmanil111","ctdeveloper","fltpmin11","fblubishnu7"'; 

    $message = "Test";
    $title = "Notification Testing";
    $imageUrl = "2024-10-06_11153_recharge_325_new_offer.jpeg&share=2024-10-06_11153.jpeg";
    
    $serviceAccountFile = '/Users/rajivbhandari/Desktop/classic-tech-firebase.json';
    $accessToken = $this->getAccessToken($serviceAccountFile); 

    $support = $this->load->database('test', TRUE);

    $limit = 200;
    $offset = 0;
    $image_path = !empty($imageUrl) ? "https://fileserver.classic.com.np/api/files/cat?path=%2F" . $imageUrl : "";
    $loopcount = 1;

    $responseArray = array();

    if (!empty($usernamesString)) 
    {
        do {
            $sql = "SELECT fcm.fcm_token, fcm.username, fcm.platform
            FROM app_fcm_token AS fcm
            WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM app_fcm_token WHERE username IN ($usernamesString) GROUP BY username)
            ORDER BY fcm.created_date DESC
            LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset ";
          
            $fcmList = $support->query($sql);
            $queryResultCount = $fcmList->num_rows();

            $resultSet = $fcmList->result_array();

            foreach ($resultSet as $row)
            {
                $fcmToken = $row['fcm_token'];

                $fcmMsg = [
                    'body' => $message,
                    'title' => $title
                ];

                $payload = [
                    'message' => [
                        'token' => $fcmToken,
                        'notification' => $fcmMsg,
                        'android' => [
                            'priority' => 'high',
                            'notification' => [
                                'sound' => 'default'
                            ]
                        ],
                        'apns' => [
                            'payload' => [
                                'aps' => [
                                    'mutable-content' => 1,
                                    'content-available' => 1
                                ]
                            ],
                            'fcm_options' => [
                                'image' => $image_path
                            ]
                        ],
                        'webpush' => [
                            'fcm_options' => [
                                'link' => $image_path
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ];

                $headers = [
                    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $accessToken,
                    'Content-Type: application/json'
                ];

                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/test-tech/messages:send');
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($payload)); 
                $result = curl_exec($ch);

                if ($result === false) {
                    $status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
                    // throw new Exception('FCM Send Error: ' . curl_error($ch), $status_code);
                }

                curl_close($ch);

                $responseArray[$row['username']] = $result;
            }

            $offset += $limit;
        } while ($queryResultCount > 0);
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($responseArray);
    exit();
}

I am expecting to send notification in batches, how do I fix it?

Can you narrow down the problem some more? Try outputting the parts of the request data that changes in each iteration of the loop ($fcmToken), followed by the response data. It might help you to notice something.
